# Clion Cmake Ninja build on Linux consuming all of the RAM and crashing PC because of that

Tags: cmake, clion, ninja

I have quite an weird issue on Linux machine where trying to build c++ project using CLion, Cmake and Ninja Generator would result in PC freezing due to all of RAM being used up. This usually happens ether when reloading CMake project or building the project itself.
Is there a way to limit how much RAM will be consumed? Currently all my 32GB + 16GB swam get eaten, I tried adding `-j4` to CMake build options, but that did not help.
EDIT: The PC did ran out of RAM for a different issue, but I still would like to limit how much ram can build and reloading take, so I'll leave my question

Comment: A nice solution was proposed here: https://www.scivision.dev/cmake-ninja-job-pool-limited-memory/

Comment: @Eivyses Have you found a solution? I"m having a similar issue - I have 20 core and 32GB of ram. I usually use `-j18` or `- j16` but still my machine freezes almost every build. In addition, Firefox tabs usually crash as well, and sometimes the machine reboots.

Comment: @ventsyv no I have not. It got somewhat better after I found a bug, but the memory usage is still quite high